# JsonConvert DeserializeObject Error

Tags: json, json.net

I am using 8.0.3 version of Json.Net and any time I try to deseralize any json into an obect. I get the following error : Missing or incorrect header for method ReadForType.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To maximize the chances of getting a useful answer, please consult the guide on how to ask questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For starters, I think that sample code and the location in the code where your error is could be useful.

Comment: Please let us know the [basic steps to reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Are you using [tag:unity3d]? This seems to be a mono/unity3d error, see the message in https://github.com/corngood/mono/blob/master/mono/mini/method-to-ir.c

Comment: I am not using unity3d. I am using Json.Net in a PCL project and any json I pass to it returns me the same error.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include what your current deserialization method looks like? It sounds as though something about it is improperly formed.